# Bigtable - read_rows and start_key

Tags: bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

Is there a way to write the `start_key` for Bigtable? I was not able to find a clear documentation on what the syntax is for `start_key`.

Suppose I have a row key of {domain}_{timestamp} of user activity.

To filter the query to a specific domain I could use a filter (slower), or a start_key (faster).

I have been writing my `start_key` string as `{domain}_`, but what if we now have `domain`, `user ID`, and `timestamp`, and now I want to filter by any user but a specific time, can I use something like `{domain}_*_{timestamp}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a Filter with [`RegexStringComparator`](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/RegexStringComparator.html).  You can also `setStart({domain}_)` for better performance. Unfortunately, that's going to pretty much going to do a scan on `{domain}_` and filter on the server-side.

It might be faster to do a search with either a random user id, or if you need all users, to use `Table.get(List<Get>)` where each `Get` correspond to individual user.

Comment: Sounds like a better solution is to keep two tables, one with {domain} row_key and the other with {domain}_{user}? So we get the fastest speed in querying.

Comment: That would work.  You just won't be able to keep those tables in sync 100% of the time, sine Cloud Bigtable doesn't have transactions across tables (or across multiple rows in the same table).